# Why I cannot use attribute installLocation in the Manifest file?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-manifest, android-sdcard

Just a simple XMl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:installLocation="auto"
        >
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Yet, I receive an error

> "No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in
>   package 'android'"

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

It seems that this is an issue with IntelliJ. At least mine. This is the screen of Project Structure. I clicked Android 2.3.3 SDK and changed its build target. I did this after the attribute

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

did not do the trick. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must specify the `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` and compile your APK using, at least, API 8. For instance:

```
....
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>
```

This will compile the APK using API 8. Handsets running Froyo or above, will be able to use that feature. Eclair and older versions won't (in this case, only Eclair).

The error happens because you are trying to compile the project with an API 7 or older, and `installLocation` was added on API 8.

[image]

Comment: Hm, this does not work in tool Intellij IDEA, which I use. I do not use Eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: I also use IntelliJ IDEA and it works fine. Do you know how to configure Android SDK in IDEA? If so, what version is your project using.

Comment: And by the way... why do you say it does not work in IntelliJ? I think you even did not tried or understand what I answered ;)

Comment: @Christian Do not bet :). I use IntelliJ 10.5, it's open all the time :). I've done dozens of projects in it, and now it suddenly stopped supporting this attribute. Funny! I will check it up in older IntelliJ 10.0.3 and let you know of result. PS. Please look at the image I added to the post

Comment: I don't mean the global SDK. I mean the SDK that uses your project. Take a look at my screenshot. Also, did you already modify your AndroidManifest file in the way I told you?

Comment: It worked. Thanks for that. But now I am TOTALLY confused. So if I set SDK 2.2, it works. It I set upper SDK 2.3+ it DOES NOT work. Why is this happening? PS. This feature worked before but obviously I was using SDK 2.2. In this project I used SDK 3.2 and the problem appeared.

Comment: That's really weird :S I just set up the project to use 3.2 and it is working fine.

Comment: True. I have double checked with SDK 2.3.3 and SDK 3.2 and the compile message appears. When I return to SDK 2.2, there is no message. I can see from the snapshot that you're using IntelliJ 10.5 as well. I did not have this message in 10.0.3. Really weird but I am glad it worked :). If you come up with the reason of such weird behaviour, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** set your build target to an API level >= 8 and your problem is solved.

Changing the build target [is easy](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html):

> Right-click the project in the Package Explorer, select Properties, select Android and then check the desired Project Target.

**Explanation:**

The [android:installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) attribute is available since API level 8, so you'll need to make sure your build target is set to API level 8 or higher, else it will not compile your application.

android:minSdkVersion can be less than 8 and your application will still work on older devices, but devices with API level < 8 will simply ignore the attribute.

Comment: Hm, this does not work in tool Intellij IDEA, which I use. I do not use Eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about IltelliJ, but take a look at this: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/android-facet.html . I guess you should be looking for File -> Project Structure -> Modules - module - Android facet and then click the 'Edit'-button to change the build target.